# Does The program flow go deeper into the bean being mocked in MockMvc?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

From what I understand about mocking, the test should not go deeper into the bean being mocked. For example the control flow shouldn't go into the function `apiService.getSomeData()` and instead it should just return the string "Hello there".
But is that how mocking works or does the program keep going deeper and should I be able to see the print statements of `getSomeData()` in the stdout?

When I actually run the code below, it doesn't go deeper. But is that how it's supposed to work?

Suppose this is the Rest Controller Code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing")
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    ApiService service;

    @PostMapping(path = "/events/notifications",consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json" )
    public ResponseEntity<String> checkMapping(@Valid @RequestBody String someData, @RequestHeader(value="X-User-Context") String xUserContext) throws Exception {
        String response  = service.getSomeData(someData);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    }
}
```

Suppose this is the Controller test code:

```java
@WebMvcTest(ApiController.class)
public class ApiControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    ApiService apiService;

    @Test
    public void testingApi() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(apiService.getSomeData("")).thenReturn("Hello there");

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockRequest = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/testing/events/notifications")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("X-User-Context","something")
                .content("something");

        mockMvc.perform(mockRequest)
                .andExpect(status().isBadGateway());

    }
}
```

Suppose this is the Api Service code:

```java
@Service
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService{

    @Override
    public String getSomeData(String data) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Going deeper in the program flow);

        callThisFunction();

        return "Some data";
    }

    public void callThisFunction(){
        System.out.println("Going two levels deeper");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to actually execute the dependency's method, use the `thenCallRealMethod` callback on the stub instead of `thenReturn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you are not talking to `ApiServiceImpl` at all, but an instance that is created by mockito and that is also implementing the `ApiService` interface. Therefore, your implementation of `getSomeData()` is not executed at all. That's what mocking is about. You create a "mock" implementation (or let a tool like mockito do it for you) of the thing you do not want to be executed and inject it instead of the "real" thing.